# Is there a shorter way to output C int with puts?

Tags: c

I'm having to do the following a lot in a USB (libusb) C based command line utility I am writing:

```
char pid[20];
sprintf(pid, "Product ID : %#06x", anInteger);
puts(pid);
```

Is there a shorter, one-liner way to do this?

Comment: Can you show the real code?  What you have there doesn't really make sense - is there supposed to be a function call on the second line?

Comment: i guess you forgot `sprintf()` at 2nd line

Comment: Oops, yes, I must have chopped it when I did the indentation.

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk now actually remove `s` from you `sprintf` it become you answer. I think silly question :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, he'll need to remove the `pid`, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use printf?

```
printf("Product ID : %#06x\n", descriptor.idVendor);
```

Comment: Ah, this one is more correct as it includes the newline! Thanks! ;)

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk if you might not forget sprintf, you could have three similar answers

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using `sprintf` & `puts`, just change to `printf`:

```
printf("Product ID : %#06x", descriptor.idVendor);
```

Comment: saving one extra function call, and memory space for `pid[]`.

Comment: Assuming `pid` was on the stack, it doesn't really save any memory.  It just pushes the stack space usage to inside `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Not with puts... You could use printf, but then you can't store the data in the pid variable. Unfortunately you can't have it both ways. You could make use of a glibc extension to printf if you're on Linux that allows you to register a custom printf format (Google should turn up something), but I don't recommend it just to save a line or two.