# Applied XOR operator with an uninitialized variable in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, undefined-behavior, xor

I'm a little bit confused. As far as I know, if you declare **uninitialized** variable in `C`, so its value is indeterminate.

> If you don’t initialize an variable that’s defined inside a function,
>   the variable value remain undefined.That means the element takes on
>   whatever value previously resided at that location in memory.

If I applied `^`(XOR) operator to uninitialized integer variable itself. Like,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int a;
        printf("%d\n", a^a);
}
```

it's clear that `a^a` should be **zero** because **the result is zero only when we have two zeroes or two ones**. So, I have a question : **Is it undefined behaviour?**

Comment: see also [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11962457/995714)

Comment: its undefined behavior only when `a==a` ... oh wait, that's UB also.

Comment: [Value of int i = i ^ i ; Is it always zero or undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17485814/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is undefined behaviour.

Attempt to use a variable with indeterminate value which

- can have trap representation
- not have it's address taken

will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's undefined behavior. Just declaring and not initializing the variable, stuff the variable with a garbage value .

Comment: `Performing xor on a value with itself gives 0 . It's undefined behavour.` isn't that contradictory? If you have a defined value, how is it UB?

Comment: @SouravGhosh , Sorry I guess my answer is a bit confusing . They are two distinct statements .

Comment: That was the point for the comment, please refine the answer and thanks for your efforts, :)